# Using AWS cloudformation to deploy public-private VPC in 2 AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am new to `AWS Cloudformation` and trying to figure out how to solve my problem with help of it.

I need a typical public internet-facing LB at the level 7 (HTTP(S)) to forward traffic into ECS Fargate instances running within the private subnet (no public IPs) via NAT devices. Pretty usual, right?

Here is what I came up with based on AWS docs and best practices so far:

```
Description:  This template deploys a VPC, with a pair of public and private subnets spread
              across two Availability Zones. It deploys an internet gateway, with a default
              route on the public subnets. It deploys a pair of NAT gateways (one in each AZ),
              and default routes for them in the private subnets.

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24

  PublicSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24

  PrivateSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.3.0/24

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ2)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ2)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  NatGateway1EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway2EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway1EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  NatGateway2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway2EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ2)
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DefaultPrivateRoute2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway2

  PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  NoIngressSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "no-ingress-sg"
      GroupDescription: "Security group with no ingress rule"
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

Outputs:
  VPC:
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnets:
    Description: A list of the public subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2 ]]

  PrivateSubnets:
    Description: A list of the private subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2 ]]

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  NoIngressSecurityGroup:
    Description: Security group with no ingress rule
    Value: !Ref NoIngressSecurityGroup
```

When I create this stack:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name dev-network --template-body file://path/to/file.yml --parameters ParameterKey=EnvironmentName,ParameterValue=test
```

...it accepts it, I see my stack being creating and shortly after that it falls into the `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`.

What am I doing wrong there? How I can make it better or, at least, quickly debug it?

---

UPD:
[image: The screenshot.]

Comment: why does it rollback? Check the Resources tab of the Stack in the web console of CloudFormation. Usually you will find some resources with status "CREATE_FAILED" which causes the rollback. Maybe your are hitting a quota limit (e.g. max. VPCs per region is 5 by default)

Comment: @Korgen `ASWLEC2:SubnetRouterTableAccosiation` with the "Resource creation cancelled". And no extra links to it. How can I debug why?

Comment: A cancelation is usually just a follow up on something else which failed before. Can you try to get the first event which is CREATE_FAILED?

Comment: @Korgen pls see screenshot in the OP. BTW, I did not delete anything. I have no idea where deletion comes from.

Comment: I've built your template successfully with no changes, so it must be a conflict with another element in your environment - perhaps a quota limit for EIP's or similar? I also built an additional stack from the same template (while leaving the first in place)and there don't seem to be any  internal conflicts. Look at the "Events" view in cloudformation to see which event threw an error and triggered the rollback.